# Why are דרשות about סוכות allowed on Shabbat?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

The Gemara in Megilah 4:1 says that if י"ד אדר falls out on שבת, you should learn about פורים on שבת. The Gemara then asks: "Why do we need to say this if we already know this from having דרשות on the שלש רגלים.
מֹשֶׁה תִּיקֵּן לָהֶם לְיִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁיְּהוּ שׁוֹאֲלִין וְדוֹרְשִׁין בְּעִנְיָנוֹ שֶׁל יוֹם: הִלְכוֹת פֶּסַח בַּפֶּסַח, הִלְכוֹת עֲצֶרֶת בָּעֲצֶרֶת,) (וְהִלְכוֹת חַג בֶּחָג!
The Gemara answers: "One may think that it is prohibited from רבה's law about not reading the Megilah on Shabbos because one might carry a Megilah to Shul."

---

Why don't we ask "Why are דרשות allowed on סוכות? Maybe someone will carry their Lulav and Esrog to Shul?!?!"

Comment: I don’t think the Gemara means to say that the drasha will be the cause to carry the Megilla. Rather the drasha will be the cause to read the Megilla, which Rabba prohibited (because of a fear of carrying, but that’s not the point here). Whereas by lulav we are not worried that the drasha will cause one to shake it. Speaking is closer to reading than to shaking. (It seems this is what rashi is trying to explain)

Comment: Rashi משום דרבה - דגזר לקמן בקריאת מגילה שמא יעבירנה ארבע אמות ברשות הרבים אף כאן גזרו דרשה אטו קרייה:

Comment: The conclusion of the gemara is we do not have this concern, so it is permitted on Purim and on Sukkos. Your question really is: Why would there be a *hava amina* to be worried on Purim, but we don't find such a *hava amina* by Sukkos? Generally, these are considered weak questions that do not necessarily require an answer.

Comment: @N.T. that was my question!

Comment: You might want to edit your question for clarity.

Comment: @N.T. that's how I read his question and I basically agree. Once the gemara asked the hava amina and answered it, it doesn't need to ask every similar hava amina and give the same answer. I also agree with Chatzkel that the hava amina is much stronger for the megillah that people will bring it to read and follow along the drasha than the hava amina they would carry the shofar or lulav to hear a drasha about RH or sukkot.